# How can I create a javascript associative array { } with dynamic key names?

Tags: jquery

Basically I have a loop incrementing i, and I want to do this:

```
var fish = { 'fishInfo[' + i + '][0]': 6 };
```

however it does not work.

Any ideas how to do this? I want the result to be

```
fish is { 'fishInfo[0][0]': 6 };
fish is { 'fishInfo[1][0]': 6 };
fish is { 'fishInfo[2][0]': 6 };
```

etc.

I am using $.merge to combine them if you think why on earth is he doing that :)

Comment: What's wrong with either (a) just creating an array; or (b) using a loop to generate the counter? What is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Declare an empty object, then you can use array syntax to assign properties to it dynamically.

```
var fish = {};

fish[<propertyName>] = <value>;
```

Comment: Cheers this sorted it. And I needed $.extend instead of $.merge :)

Answer (score 5):

Do this:

```
var fish = {};
fish['fishInfo[' + i + '][0]'] =  6;
```

It works, because you can read & write to objects using square brackets notation like this:

```
my_object[key] = value;
```

and this:

```
alert(my_object[key]);
```

Answer (score 2):

For any dynamic stuff with object keys, you need the *bracket notation*.

```
var fish = { };

fish[ 'fishInfo[' + i + '][0]' ] = 6;
```

Answer (score 0):

Multidimensional Arrays in javascript are created by saving an array inside an array.

Try:

```
var multiDimArray = [];
for(var x=0; x<10; x++){
    multiDimArray[x]=[];
    multiDimArray[x][0]=6;
}
```

Fiddle Exampe: http://jsfiddle.net/CyK6E/